# Create a fragment and send data to it

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is what I do to create a new fragment (called `AlbumsTrackFragment`) and replace the existing one :

```
AlbumsTrackFragment albumstrackfragment = new AlbumsTrackFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_ipod, albumstrackfragment, "albumsTrackfragment");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
albumstrackfragment.DoTask(data);
```

The problem is that when I can't call the method `DoTask()` and pass the new fragment some data because the app crashes, indeed I get : `Content view not yet created`

How can I wait that the `commit` was performed to call `DoTask()` method of my fragment ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider passing in data to your fragment through DoTask and then wait until OnActivityCreated() is called to perform whatever action happens in DoTask. This way you are passing in your data but not doing anything until your view is loaded and won't crash.